# finding and renaming large *.jpg to *.jpeg

Tags: bash, find, rename

I have a large and messy collection of file--*hey who doesn't*--some of these are large JPGs (large in this case is an arbitrary number, say 2.5MB) that I want to rename--I want to change the extension from `*.jpg` to `*.jpeg.`

I'd love to do this with a shell script, I'm running `BASH 3.2.39(1)`, and I have a feeling this is "simple" task with `find`, alas I find find's syntax difficult to remember and the man page impossible to read.

Any and all help with be most appreciated.

Comment: The *size* of the files is not important here.

Comment: Are you saying you only want to rename files that are bigger than 2.5MB?

Comment: Hammarstrom's got it, I think; yes, I am looking to rename files larger than 2.5MB or some other threshold.

Answer (score 7):

Finding and renaming large files could be done like this:

`find . -size +2500k -exec rename -s .jpg .jpeg '{}' ';'`

Comment: I get `Unknown option: s`
what's the `-s` option intended to do?

Comment: @Dan: Depends on which `rename` you have on your computer. Debian-based distros uses perl `prename`. Use `rename.ul` instead. See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=439935

Comment: thanks @christoffer-hammarstrom; I used `rename.ul` without the `-s` flag and it worked; while with the `-s` flag it did not.

Comment: @Dan would you please mark this answer as the right answer? Because you wrote that it did what it should so I guess it was the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using? In most repositories there is an app called mmv which is perfect for these kinds of things..

usage:
`mmv \*.jpg \#1.jpeg`

Comment: This doesn't discriminate by file size, however.

Answer (score 1):

Install rename (standard tool in your linux installation or with homebrew for mac), then:

```
rename -s .jpg .jpeg *
```

or, if you have files in subdirectories too:

```
rename -s .jpg .jpeg $(find . -name '*.jpg')
```

Comment: This doesn't discriminate by file size, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.jpg
do
 new_name= $(echo $i|sed 's/.jpg/.jpeg/')
 mv $i $new.name
done
```

Comment: again...how does this discriminate based on the size of the file?